# Compilation error when using inner class

Tags: java

Currently learning about inner class. I have two classes. In second class there is an inner class. I am trying to create an object of the inner class in the second class. But I am getting compilation error. Can anyone help?

Here is my code:

```
public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        NestedClass.NewUser newUserObj = new NewUser("User");
        System.out.println(newUserObj.Name);
    }
}

class NestedClass {

    class NewUser {
        public String Name;

        NewUser(String name) {
            this.Name = name;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To instantiate an inner class, you must first instantiate the outer class.

Create the inner object using the outer object as shown below:

```
NestedClass.NewUser newUserObj = (new NestedClass()).new NewUser("User");
```

Reference: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html

Answer (score 2):

You can only create an instance of `NewUser` with an instance of `NestedClass`.

```
new NestedClass().new NewUser("User");
```

Answer (score 2):

Despite the name `NestedClass` is not a nested class but rather an outer class, so an instance of `NestedClass` is required to create an instance of the real nested class, i.e. `NewUser`

```
NestedClass.NewUser newUserObj = new NestedClass().new NewUser("User");
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternate option: make the inner class `static`. Then, technically, it's no longer an "inner" class but only a "nested" class, and you can instantiate it with `new NestedClass.NewUser()`. As explained in the [Nested Classes Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html), static nested classes can be instantiated without having an instance of the enclosing class, like the other answers refer to.